# OTAClient.dll / TDAPIOLIB Recurring Access Violation Error during data pull

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2013, alm

Okay gang, this one has been driving me up a wall for three days.

I've written an application that pulls data from HP's Application Lifecycle Management system using their functionality. The OTAClient.dll is directly from Hewlett Packard. Namespace is actually TDAPOlib in the code however.

The application itself, runs fine. All of the methods correctly pull data for other projects identified in the system. But whenever it is ran, the OTAClient.dll will inevitably explode with a 0xC000005 Access Read Violation warning that cannot be ignored. You can continue through until completion but as it is row by row this is impossible to do.

I've gone through and groomed the data in the system extensively to ensure that it meets the requirements of the application. I know the permissions are right. I have the most up to date OTAClient taken directly from HP. I know all methods I've written work correctly.

My only theory is that there is some kind of version conflict between the .dll and Visual Studio. I updated to Ultimate 2013 today to see if it changed anything and the application did run longer than it had before. I deleted all registry entries that might have possibly referenced. Ultimately it has to do with OTAclient not  being backwards compatible... with something. I just have no idea what it could possibly be.

[image]

This image is taken from the call stack at the moment of the access violation. This tells me that the OTAClient is causing it.

Mainly I am just looking for any idea as to where to look. Did I miss something? Should I look somewhere else?

Thank You for your assistance.

Comment: Can you reduce your program to the minimum code required to reproduce the problem then post the code here? You should check the version of OTACLIENT.DLL and WEBCLIENT.DLL matches exactly the version on the HPQC server. Even slight differences have caused me problems.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the API extensively with C#, and have never had this issue.  Steps I typically follow:

1. Open the ALM application in my web browser just to make sure all the pre-requisite software is loaded (not really necessary, but I feel better knowing that it runs).
2. Open the Add-ins Page of the ALM Application and perform the client registration.  This is necessary to register the COM components on the machine
3. In Visual Studio, add the "OTA COM Type Library" component to my project

After that, I can create objects using `var tdc = new TDConnectionClass();` to begin using the API.

Comment: This is exactly how I use it.

Comment: I've had numerous issues with the ALM client (not just the OTA Cient) having memory problems, specifically read access violations.  Could just be an issue with the client DLL and it not managing memory well.  Check that you've installed all the available patches for your version of ALM.  Also make sure you're application is being compiled for x86 architecture, not x64.

Comment: I've narrowed it down some more. I was able to forcibly write to the memory location that it stops at when the application is not running. Thus, he OTAclient seems to be reserving a location in the memory, and then not letting me do anything with it...